# React, route passing props undefined from one component to another?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
import React from "react";
import { Route} from "react-router-dom";
import EditFeatureRow from './Edit_FeatureRow';
export class Edit_Features extends React.Component {
       constructor(props) {
              super(props);
              this.state = {
                     Feature_ID: "",   FeatureName:
                     Feature: [],     loading: true,
              };
       }
       componentDidMount() {
       this.DisplayFeatures();
       }
}
componentDidUpdate() {
       this.DisplayFeatures();
}}
       DisplayFeatures() {
       fetch(REQUEST_URL)
                     .then(response => response.json())
                     .then((data) => {
                           this.setState({
                                  Feature: data,
                                  Feature_ID: data[0].featureID,
                                  FeatureName: data[0].featureName,
                                  loading: false
                           })
                     })
                     .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
}
       render() {
              return (
                     <div>
<form
**<Route path="/Edit_FeatureRow">
<EditFeatureRow key_id={this.state.Feature_ID} />
</Route>**
{this.state.Feature.map((item, index) => {
return [
       <div width="100%">
<table>
              <tr><td>                  
                     **<Link to="/Edit_FeatureRow"> Edit</Link>**
                     </td>
                     <td>{item.featureID}</td>
                     <td>{item.featureName}</td>
                     </tr>
     </div>];})}</table></div>
</form></div>
              );
       }
}
export default Edit_Features;
_______________________

import React from "react";
export class Edit_FeatureRow extends React.Component {
       constructor(props) {
              super(props);
              this.state = {
                     Feature_ID: "", FeatureName: "",
                    loading: true,
              };
              this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
       //     this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
       }
       componentDidMount() {
              const Feature_ID = this.props.key_id;
              if (typeof this.props.key_id !== 'undefined') {
                     this.DisplayFeatureDetails(Feature_ID);
              }
       }
       componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
              const Feature_ID = this.props.key_id;
              if (prevProps.key_id !== this.props.key_id) {
                     console.log(`key_id: ${this.props.key_id}`);
                     this.DisplayFeatureDetails(Feature_ID);
              }
       }
       DisplayFeatureDetails(Feature_ID) {
              fetch(REQUEST_URL, { "Content-Type": "application/xml; charset=utf-8" })
                     .then(response => response.json())
                     .then((data) => {
                           this.setState({
                                  Feature_ID: this.props.key_id,
                                  FeatureName: data[0].featureName,
                                  loading: false
                           })
                     })
                     .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
       }
       handleChange(event) {
              this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
       }
    render() {
        return (                    
            <div>
                           <form>                                 
<div>{this.state.Feature_ID}{ this.state.FeatureName}</div> 
              </form>
             </div >
        );
   }
} 
export default Edit_FeatureRow;
```

I am displaying data in Edit_Features Component. With each row, there is an edit link. Edit link will open another component Edit_FeatureRow. Edit_Features is having the value Feature_ID which is passing to Edit_FeatureRow component. Feature_ID is undefined in Edit_FeatureRow component. Please help.

````
import React from "react";
import { Route} from "react-router-dom";
import EditFeatureRow from './Edit_FeatureRow';
export class Edit_Features extends React.Component {
       constructor(props) {
              super(props);
              this.state = {
                     Feature_ID: "",   FeatureName:
                     Feature: [],     loading: true,
              };
       }
       componentDidMount() {
       this.DisplayFeatures();
       }
}
componentDidUpdate() {
       this.DisplayFeatures();
}}
       DisplayFeatures() {
       fetch(REQUEST_URL)
                     .then(response => response.json())
                     .then((data) => {
                           this.setState({
                                  Feature: data,
                                  Feature_ID: data[0].featureID,
                                  FeatureName: data[0].featureName,
                                  loading: false
                           })
                     })
                     .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
}
       render() {
              return (
                     <div>
<form
**<Route path="/Edit_FeatureRow">
<EditFeatureRow key_id={this.state.Feature_ID} />
</Route>**
{this.state.Feature.map((item, index) => {
return [
       <div width="100%">
<table>
              <tr><td>                  
                     **<Link to="/Edit_FeatureRow"> Edit</Link>**
                     </td>
                     <td>{item.featureID}</td>
                     <td>{item.featureName}</td>
                     </tr>
     </div>];})}</table></div>
</form></div>
              );
       }
}
export default Edit_Features;
_______________________
 
import React from "react";
export class Edit_FeatureRow extends React.Component {
       constructor(props) {
              super(props);
              this.state = {
                     Feature_ID: "", FeatureName: "",
                    loading: true,
              };
              this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
       //     this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
       }
       componentDidMount() {
              const Feature_ID = this.props.key_id;
              if (typeof this.props.key_id !== 'undefined') {
                     this.DisplayFeatureDetails(Feature_ID);
              }
       }
       componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
              const Feature_ID = this.props.key_id;
              if (prevProps.key_id !== this.props.key_id) {
                     console.log(`key_id: ${this.props.key_id}`);
                     this.DisplayFeatureDetails(Feature_ID);
              }
       }
       DisplayFeatureDetails(Feature_ID) {
              fetch(REQUEST_URL, { "Content-Type": "application/xml; charset=utf-8" })
                     .then(response => response.json())
                     .then((data) => {
                           this.setState({
                                  Feature_ID: this.props.key_id,
                                  FeatureName: data[0].featureName,
                                  loading: false
                           })
                     })
                     .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
       }
       handleChange(event) {
              this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
       }
    render() {
        return (                    
            <div>
                           <form>                                 
<div>{this.state.Feature_ID}{ this.state.FeatureName}</div> 
              </form>
             </div >
        );
   }
} 
export default Edit_FeatureRow;```
````

Comment: This code is so hard to read, I would suggest putting it through a linter if you expect answers

Answer (score 0):

from react-router perspective.
and I assume you are using react-router v5.*

**1. in the Edit_Features component.**

you need to do your Route and Link as follow, the route should be expect id

```
<Route path="/edit_FeatureRow/:id">
      {(props) => (
        <EditFeatureRow key_id={this.state.Feature_ID} {...props} />
      )}
   </Route>
```

and the link to pass the id to it.

```
 <Link to={`/edit_FeatureRow/${item.featureID}`}>
     Edit
 </Link>
```

**2. in the Edit_FeatureRow component**

you should expect the id from router through props.
like this

```
this.props.match.params.id
```

this snippet can help you
[live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-stonebraker-7j1n3m?file=/src/EditFeatureRow.js)

Comment: Thanks Samehanwar. I tried your solution. Its giving me the issue: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'params')

{this.props.match.params.id}

Its passing the id in the url: edit_FeatureRow/123. In the ComponentDidMount, its returning null value for Feature_ID in edit_FeatureRow component.

Comment: @TestUser, you need to check for null first before rendering the id like this.
{this.props.match && this.props.match.params.id}.
i updated the demo

Comment: this.props.match && this.props.match.params.id is still returning null with the new code. In the url its passing the id, but in edit_FeatureRow data is not showing as this.props.match && this.props.match.params.id value is null. please help.

Comment: @TestUser it looks fine on my side without errors

Comment: Thereis an error in the Sandbox, In VisualStudio ths routing error is not present Please help why this.props.match && this.props.match.params.id is still returning null . Please find my Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-dream-7guy5m?file=/src/Edit_Features.js

Comment: @TestUser try this link in the browser
https://7j1n3m.csb.app/edit_Feature

Comment: I tried your solution, its passing id in the url. In the componentdidmount of edit_FeatureRow, this.props.match && this.props.match.params.id is null. Also, how to open edit_FeatureRow component in  popup window on edit link click?